# sed unexpected ',' error

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I'm trying to use the sed command to find a string and delete the line it is on plus the next line. I'm trying to do this on a server running RedHat v7.1, c shell

I enter:

```
sed '/Non Unique Subdivision/,+1d' Orig_text.txt > text.txt
```

I get this message:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 26: Unexpected ','

I've tried running the command with a '-e' on it too; get the same result. I tried doing a similar command with the same syntax on an Ubuntu terminal and it works. So I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with RedHat, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Anyone see this before, or know a workaround?

Comment: FYI, on "CentOS release 6.5" it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+1` syntax is not standard sed.  Try:

```
sed '/Non Unique Subdivision/,/^/d'
```

or

```
sed '/Non Unique Subdivision/{N;d;}'
```